# Removing character before given pattern in R

Tags: r

I have an object called `my.files` which contains full path to the files I want to work with. I need to remove the characters before (including) "BAM/" and only keep the characters after `"BAM/"` and get the `result`. I want to use this in a loop as a column name for the output, so one liner would be more suitable.

```
my.files<-c("/media/BAM/14066.bam","/data/BAM/14091.bam","/code/BAM/sort.bam","/media/BAM/ReCal.sort.bam")
```

result

```
"14066.bam"  "14091.bam"  "sort.bam"  "ReCal.sort.bam"
```

Comment: `sapply(strsplit(my.files, "/"), tail, n=1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> gsub("(.+)BAM/", "", my.files)
[1] "14066.bam"      "14091.bam"      "sort.bam"       "ReCal.sort.bam"
```

Comment: Or just `gsub(".*BAM/", "", my.files)`

Answer (score 1):

I would anchor the match to the end of your file path, as a general solution.

```
sub(".*/(.+)$", "\\1", my.files)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to extract the base name of the file path.  It can done using the already available `basename` function.

```
basename(my.files)
#[1] "14066.bam"      "14091.bam"      "sort.bam"       "ReCal.sort.bam"
```

Or another option is `str_extract` from `stringr` using some regex lookarounds.  Here we match the characters that are not `/` (`[^/]+`) which follows a `/` (`(?<=/)`) until the end of the string (`$`).

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(my.files, '(?<=/)[^/]+$')
#[1] "14066.bam"      "14091.bam"      "sort.bam"       "ReCal.sort.bam"
```